# Confusion in proportional controller

Tags: control-system, output, system, controller

I was revising proportional controller from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.electrical4u.com/types-of-controllers-proportional-integral-derivative-controllers/&ved=2ahUKEwiR1_Si6cnxAhWxzjgGHcisAtQQFnoECDIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw04dRm8mCuXjQtBC4Zs6Qnr)
and got confused in following figure which is common in many books also.

[image]

1. Since output of controller is proportional(by factor K) to error function but error function and output of plant have same unit(otherwise substraction not possible) which implies that input and output of plant should have same unit or in other words should be proportional but how this is even possible when we already know that there is no such constraints on the plant and plant may have any possible input output relation,so where  my reasoning is   wrong ?

2.And if we assume plant is an integrator then is it implies that  proportional controller should be a differentiator , so that at least variables  dimensionally makes sense  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a purely theoretical presentation, everything is dimensionless.  You get this in basic control theory because control systems are difficult and complicated, and trying to deal with everything at once means you just won't get there.  So first you learn how to do it in mathemagic land, and then you learn (in a class or on your own) how to translate that to the real world.

In the real world, as you point out, things have dimensions.  A much more realistic block diagram is shown below.  G1 would have an input in whatever domain the summation block is working (most likely digital numbers, but maybe volts or PSI or whatever).  It would have an output in whatever the input of H is -- so, more digital numbers (if, for instance, you're modeling your DAC as part of "the plant"), or volts, or PSI, or liters of sewage per second, or whatever.

H, would, presumably, have some real-world output, i.e. meters of sewage* or volts or degrees C.  G2 would have the same input, and its output would be the units of the summation block.

So G1 may be in units of volts/LSB (where "LSB" is a stand in for "1", and emphasizes that you're dealing with computer numbers), H may be in units of m/V, and then G2 would have to be in units of LSB/m.

When you're actually modeling this stuff, a quick trip around the loop, checking that dimensions are consistent with gains, is a good way to avoid errors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ38ZX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

* I'm trying to make control systems look as romantic as possible here.

Comment: Thanks for very detailed question , if let's say H (in your figure) block represent plant which is an integrator (a partical of mass m whose input is force and output is velocity ) , and G2 block is proportional sensor which measure the velocity of partical and gives an output in voltage which then substract from reference voltage (calibrated velocity to voltage ) and then error voltage is multiplied(because it is proportional controller) by a factor constant K but again we have to use a block (G1) which convert the multiplied error  voltage into force  but this is where

Comment: I'm confused how to design G1 which gives desired result , is G1 is just a random proportional unit converter from voltage to force or there is some relation between transfer function of plant and of G1?

Comment: You're not so much _designing_ G1 as _describing_ it.  H is your plant, as you've described it.  The summation junction operates in the domain of your controller.  G1, perforce, has units of (plant input dimension)/(controller domain).

Answer (score 1):

> Since output of controller is proportional(by factor K) to error function but error function and output of plant have same unit(otherwise substraction not possible) which implies that input and output of plant should have same unit

The proportional gain `K` need not be unitless. So the input of the plant and the output of the plant can have different units.

For example, a temperature control system, the proportional gain unit can be something like (cc/s)/degree, if the input to the heater is fuel gas flow rate.

Another example, for a vehicle cruise control, the proportional gain can have the units of mm/(mph) where the plant input is the throttle position (in mm).